# Man pages are shuffled

Tags: ubuntu, man

`man` has no section 2. `/usr/share/man/man2` is empty. `fork(2)` is actually `fork(3)` and there is no `printf(3)`, `printf(2)`, `execve(2)`, or `execve(3)`. How do I fix my man pages?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and `man-db` is already installed and reinstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [execve(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/execve.2.html), [fork(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/fork.2.html) and [printf(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/printf.3.html) manpages are all in the [manpages-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/manpages-dev/filelist) package:

```
sudo apt install manpages-dev
```

will make them available.